# Why are Wolverine's teeth not Adamantium coated?

Tags: marvel, comics, wolverine

Wolverine's skeleton is fully coated with Adamantium, [even his claws](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12141/45). But his teeth don't seem to be Adamantium coated, or at least he doesn't have [Jaws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaws_%28James_Bond%29#Jaws)'s smile. Why?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Whilst still calcified, [teeth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teeth_%28human%29#Parts) are not bone in the sense that his skeleton is. They grow and change in a different way. It's also possible when his healing factor adapted to the infusion of Adamantium it forced the metal out of his teeth.

Furthermore, as [HNL points out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14331/3804), when the Adamantium was first injected, it was only into his bones, not into his teeth. I doubt it would have gotten very far before solidifying however, so there must have been some factor spreading it about his body. Whatever this was probably missed or couldn't effect his teeth.

Comment: Plus teeth are made of dentin, not bone. A Jaws smile would be pretty sweet, though, DavRob.

Comment: And if one could assert logic to this comically preposterous scenario, having his teeth remain unaffected isn't much different than his ligaments and cartilage also not being affected, among every other part of his body that isn't bone, or whatever the writers decided to inject adamentium into.

Answer (score 15):

The Adamantium infusion (especially as shown in the *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*) appears to involve drilling into all the major bones and feeding the alloy into the marrow. I doubt his teeth were ever drilled into. He has to rely on his usual healing factor to survive blows to his teeth.

Answer (score -1):

Teeth you see in an X-ray grow more like a tree with roots from the gums and are separated from our actual skeleton. That's why you can lose and grow new teeth through your lifetime and losing a tooth isn't considered a broken or lost bone.

Comment: Whilst some nice information you may want to [edit] this to explain how this applies to Wolverine and his teeth and Adamantium skeleton.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  On its own this doesn't make a complete answer, because it doesn't explain why either it was not possible to alloy his teeth with adamantium or a choice was made not to inject adamantium into them.

Comment: Humans get baby teeth and adult teeth. That is not "you can lose and grow new teeth through your lifetime", it's twice, both of them relatively early in one's lifetime.