# Could the Muramasa Blade cut through Adamantium? What can't it cut through?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

In a comment on [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14347/1913) to [How to kill Wolverine?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14347/how-to-kill-wolverine/14366#14366), Thaddeus Howze commented:

> The blade's molecular properties will have no effect on his adamantium bones.

I was under the impression that the Muramasa Blade (the one forged specifically for Wolverine, not the Black Blade) could cut basically *anything.* It apparently cut through **one of Cyclops' eye beams** once. However, it apparently can't cut through Armor's powered-by-her-ancestors-or-something armor, and its ability to cut through adamantium is suspect.

So can the Muramasa Blade cut through adamantium? Are there other things it can't cut through?

Comment: *Another* Muramasa blade? A lightsaber?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Wolverine: Origins #35, the Muramasa Blade can cut through "anything, that is, except a memory". That is the explanation given as to why Armor's mutant power can resist the Blade.  Given that comment and Wolverine's belief that the Blade "is the only thing in the world that can put me down for good", I would argue that it probably can cut through adamantium (though that has yet to be tested), and that the only thing(s) it cannot cut are those not physical in nature.

[image]

Comment: The line from Wolverine: Origins is very encouraging - do you know what issue it appeared in?

Comment: #33-35 are the three with Armor in it, according to ComicVine but I don't have the issues handy to confirm which (if it is one of these).

Comment: There we go, found the reference.

Answer (score 2):

`Muramasa Blade vs. Adamantium` is never shown in Marvel universe. But, if you really want explanation for winning Adamantium, here it is..

According to official [Marvel Universe Wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Adamantium):

> The only substance able to pierce Adamantium is the compound
>   known as Antarctic Vibranium, also called "anti-metal".

From [Marvel @ Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Muramasa_Blade):

> Muramasa used a piece of Wolverine's soul in forging this blade, just
>   as he used a piece of his own in forging the Black Blade. This sword
>   is also made of an unknown alloy that was originally bright red in
>   color, but now has the color of a conventional blade.

As Muramasa blade isn't made up of Antarctic Vibranium, it can't cut Adamantium.

It works against Wolverine's regeneration powers because [it destroys organic lump](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14389/931) (important for mutant powers). It doesn't mean, it can work against Adamantium. Slicing Adamantium at molecular level wouldn't be possible.

When it comes to soul based ju-ju of blade, Wolverine wasn't born with his Adamantium. Soul should be working only against the part under control of soul itself.

Comment: The Muramasa Blade "sliced, on the molecular level" through a S.H.I.V.A. robot - was the robot related to Wolverine's soul somehow? IMO, the fact that part of his soul was incorporated is what gives it the supernatural ability to cut at the molecule level, and that supernatural cutting is what negates people's healing factors.

Comment: @IanPugsley The soul part is reply of: `the one forged specifically for Wolverine`..

Comment: And, a piece of soul was used in forging black blade, too. Don't say Wolverine's soul makes red one more powerful.

Comment: Adamantium is proof against any kind of energy, matter or attack once it has been set into its final form. It takes the powers of Omega level mutants (like Magneto), Asgardian gods like Odin, or cosmic beings like the Silver Surfer or Thanos to change or deform it after it has been set. The Muramasa Blade not need to do anything but sever Logan's vertebra which are not magically connected with Adamantium allowing for them to be separated without molecular matter' slicing powers to be used.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze You are right, but question is asking different thing..

Answer (score 1):

In the most recent wolverine comic, a muramasa cut through the Adamantium reinforce skin of solem.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are these images in the correct sequence?

Comment: Accidentally did it in the wrong arrangement, but it is in the same comic book!