# How does the Muramasa Blade block Wolverine's regeneration capability?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine

Wolverine's mutant powers can't heal him faster if he is wounded by the red [Muramasa Blade](http://marvel.wikia.com/Muramasa_Blade) (not the old black).

From the linked Wiki:

> In a subsequent fight with
>   Captain America, the sword was used against Wolverine, leaving a
>   scar on his chest, which oddly didn't heal as usual. After the fight
>   was over, Wolverine gave the sword to Cyclops, explaining it by
>   saying: "**This is the only thing in the world that can put me down for
>   good.**"

[image: Muramasa Blade]

I want to know how this blade works such that it can block the regeneration powers of Wolverine.

Comment: Comments explaining downvote would be nice..

Comment: I think you should ask for more information in the [relevant answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14366/2057) instead of making a new question.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Why is that? This is not a discussion forum. SE rules prohibit that.

Comment: @MikePeterson - There is nothing prohibiting a user from asking for clarification or more information on an answer they find lacking.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot This is a **brand-new question**. Do check questions in any popular tag, you can find many questions/answers related to each other. That answer doesn't need clarification.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Yes.. I was inspired by that answer! I should have put its credit in question.. :) specially, for photo..

Comment: @MikePeterson I am fully aware of how many "brand new questions" exist on the site that are simply spawned in order to clarify existing answers.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Mike is right. Author of that answer put the facts with citation which was demand of its question. But, it doesn't mean he is necessarily expert of telling `How It Works`. So that I asked as question.. it really deserves separate space!

Comment: I added detail that I think clarifies it better. sorry for not doing so from the get-go.

Answer (score 8):

In the Marvel Database it says: 'The second Muramasa Blade's location was revealed to Wolverine by the Silver Samurai[4]. This sword, currently wielded by Wolverine, was a sword forged specifically for him by Muramasa. On their first meeting in Japan, Wolverine came to Muramasa after his wife Itzu had been murdered, so he could help him to "kill 'em all". Muramasa accepted, and promised to forge him a "mighty blade -...- against which all... even one as great as you... will fall" using a piece of Wolverine's soul. When Logan came to claim the weapon[5], Muramasa gladly gave it to him, telling him to "wield it like an angry god".'

My guess would be that since the blade was made with a piece of Wolverine's soul, that it may cancel out his (and other's) healing factors through some sort of resonant quality.

Also, from the same wiki article, it mentions that a robot that was sliced in two was not just sliced, but was actually affected at the molecular level. This could also suggest that the damage done is at too low of a level for most healing factors to recover from. I'm guessing that molecular level damage would result in the wounds edges no longer necessarily being the same organic substances, leaving a sort of irregular scar. This could interfere significantly with the healing process.

You can read more here: http://marvel.wikia.com/Muramasa_Blade

Comment: This doesn't describe *how* the sword works, this only describes its origin. It's worked on other healing factors (Sabretooth, Daken), so it's not meant just to kill Wolverine.

Comment: I added some information

Answer (score 8):

Per [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Muramasa_Blade)

> The Black Blade is many centuries old and possesses a variety of mystical properties that it possesses in and of itself and properties that it grants to those who wield it.

But we're discussing the Red blade.

> The blade has easily cut through the armor of a S.H.I.V.A. (Earth-616). robot on a molecular level and has also "sliced" one of Cyclops' optic beams into several different beams and reflected them in different directions. The sword is also capable of greatly reducing the efficiency of a superhumanly fast healing rate.

Granted, the second passage does not address exactly "how" it works, but the first passage explains that the Muramasa blades are imbued with mystical properties and abilities. As much of a cop-out as it sounds, it seems that as of now, the best answer possible is, "it's magic." I do, however, make note of the second passage because it discusses the blades ability to do damage at a molecular level. While unexplained, it's possible that the blade may be able to damage enough of Wolverine's cells in such a way that it slows down his healing factor.

Answer (score 2):

From [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Muramasa_Blade) page:

> Wolverine used it against a S.H.I.V.A. robot, cutting it in half with
>   a single blow. Later research of the remains of the robot showed that
>   **it was not cut**, but rather "**sliced, on the molecular level**". The
>   scientist who was doing the research theorized, that the instrument
>   could have been some sort of plasmic form.

Muramasa Blade doesn't cut, but slice the matter at molecular level. Wolverine's regeneration power is meant to work from cell or any biological level. As blade cuts on molecular level, the organic matter is destroyed (organic matter is made up of many molecules). So, his regeneration fails to work.

Comment: "Cut" and "sliced on the molecular level" are not really different.  That's what cutting _is_.  If you turn one piece of metal into two pieces of metal, the only way to do it is to sever metallic bonds.  I guess this is just shorthand for "it's a lot sharper than anything you're used to".