# What happens when Wolverine's head is removed?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

In the situation where Wolverine has his head cut off (which I am sure would be no simple task, most likely requiring an adamantium weapon of some form) -

What would happen?

Would his head regrow a new body? Or would his body regrow a new head? This question specifically deals with what happens after the decapitation with Wolverine's regenerative abilities. Has this already been covered via comics?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79236/can-wolverine-be-decapitated-by-an-adamantium-based-weapon

Comment: @JasonBaker Sure is related (and a incredibly well put together question. ) I will edit my question in the interests of clarity.

Comment: Also see: [How much of Wolverine has to be left to heal?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12486/5184) and [Out of two organic lumps of Wolverine, what decides which one would regenerate to full Wolverine?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14417/5184)

Comment: Wolverine has regenerated from a single cell in non 616 canon.

Answer (score 11):

His head and body both stay alive but they are useless until someone puts them together then he will start healing.

[image]

Comment: Then the question to ask would be how much of his body would be required. ?

Comment: Ahem - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12486/how-much-of-wolverine-has-to-be-left-to-heal

Comment: And how is he talking without lungs to draw in and push out air?

Answer (score 2):

In the mainstream universe, decapitation would kill him.

In the ultimate universe, his power is survival instead of healing, his skin would take in oxygen for his brain if he's just a head.

Comment: Can you cite any instance of decapitation killing him in Earth-616?

Comment: Prof. Xavier himself  said that that was most likely the only way to kill him, no one has actually tried it. Wolverine also used a special sword (don't know how it was special) to kill Sabretooth. And Sabretooth mentioned an oxygen deprived brain might kill him i.e. drowning

Comment: You're likely thinking of [the muramasa blade](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14380/how-does-the-muramasa-blade-block-wolverines-regeneration-capability). And as you've mentioned, Xavier and Sabretooth mention ways that *might* work. Theories are fine. Evidence is better.

Comment: Just to clarify: I'm not at all saying your answer is bad or wrong - just that it would be a lot better with some evidence or citations edited in.