# How can Wolverine speak without a body?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

In this question: [What happens when Wolverine's head is removed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/what-happens-when-wolverines-head-is-removed) the following panel appears:

[image]

Does it imply that that Wolverine can speak without lungs. Is this a super power or some other method of communication?

Comment: It doesn't look like he'd have vocal chords there, either, though IANAL (I Am Not A Laryngologist)

Comment: It looks like there's some kind of support technology behind and beside his head.

Comment: I'm flashing on [*Jan in the Pan*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TheBrainThatWouldntDie)

Comment: I *wonder* just what type of research he does in the closet ...

Comment: Is comic rule of funny. Don't over think it

Comment: I like @JoeL.'s explanation.  Does anyone have other stills from this scene, that might indicate whether the tech on that table is helping him talk?

Comment: He draws breath from the same place that he gets the extra biomass when he regenerates.

Comment: @Paulster2 it's research for academic purposes

Comment: maybe Wolverine is simply moving his mouth, and Fury is just reading his lips?

Comment: Let me get this straight... This is a universe with mutants, where this one can regenerate pretty much his entire body, who also was infused with a silly strong metal... and you wonder how he can speak without means to force air ?

Comment: He isn't speaking. Spoken words don't look like that. Spoken words don't look like anything. Those are written words. A letterer who still has all their body parts (probably) is writing those words down.

Answer (score 2):

The panel in your question is from *Ultimate Wolverine vs Hulk* #5. There are a couple of facts to be kept in mind before drawing conclusions:

- There is some machinery attached to his head:

  [image]

  This machinery may or may not be providing him with air to speak.
- His lungs are away. How does he breathe? With his skin.

  [image]

I think it's most likely that the machinery (all the tubes) is feeding him air that allows him to speak, and maybe keeps his blood circulating for him.

One other possibility is that those headphone-like things are reading his mind and feeding it to speakers, but that wouldn't explain why Nick Fury had to interrogate him to learn something, instead of just extracting what he needed.

Yet another possibility is that *somehow*, Logan was able to adapt and speak without lungs, but that wouldn't explain the need for all the machinery.

Answer (score 0):

Probably by the same mechanisms used to keep him alive in the movies. In the movies, Wolverine lives for centuries because his body is able to regenerate itself after every possible trauma. We get to watch the cellular regeneration in the movies as bullets are removed and tissues are created to replace what was destroyed. He also has super human strength. So it is reasonable to assume that the same mechanism works in the comics. So the likely answer is that he grew new vocal cords along with the strength to use air that his severed trachea is able to pull from below outside his body.

Comment: The trachea doesn't pull air. The diaphragm pushes it up. The diaphragm is below the lungs.

Comment: @dcshannon Only if yer head has not been severed.