# If Wolverine's head was cut off, would it grow back?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine, regeneration

The inspiration for my question is from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFm982JyE4A),

> which operates under the assumption that Wolverine's head would not grow back.

Is this an accurate assumption to make?

### Edit

I think it's apparent that if his head is destroyed in the way depicted, the adamantium skull would not regenerate, but there seems to be conflicting accepted answers within the two suggested questions this might be a duplicate of. In [What happens when Wolverine's head is removed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/what-happens-when-wolverines-head-is-removed), the accepted answer is that

> His head and body both stay alive but they are useless until someone puts them together then he will start healing.

If his head is destroyed, the body will not recover then? But in [Out of two organic lumps of Wolverine, what decides which one would regenerate to full Wolverine?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14417/out-of-two-organic-lumps-of-wolverine-what-decides-which-one-would-regenerate-t), the accepted answer is that

> Wolverine recovers his memories and personality even after most of his brain is destroyed.

There is still no clear agreement on this speculation, thus my question.

Comment: Actually I meant this one. [What happens when Wolverine's head is removed?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/what-happens-when-wolverines-head-is-removed)

Comment: @JackBNimble I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

According to @phantom42's answer (see [How to kill Wolverine?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14347/how-to-kill-wolverine)), beheading Wolverine would kill him. It is apparently one of the "Xavier Protocols" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_X#Xavier_Protocols) drawn up as a contingency in the event that one of the X-Men needed to be taken out.

Comment: I found the quote in phantom42's answer, and it appears that wikipedia no longer has that section in the Xavier Protocols page. I see no reference anywhere laying out the protocol in detail for killing Wolverine.

Comment: From http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Xavier_Protocols: Long range attack, sever the head, and place the head and body far apart.
**Note: This assumes Wolverine is without his adamantium skeleton.**