# How did Punisher kill Wolverine?

Tags: comics, marvel, wolverine, the-punisher

Of all the characters to kill off, Punisher, in a one-shot comic book called '[Punisher Kills the Marvel Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punisher_Kills_the_Marvel_Universe)',  manages to finish off Wolverine.

The wiki article is vague; how does Punisher kill off Wolverine?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Punisher blew up all of the other X-Men and most of the major X-Men villains in a giant nuclear explosion on the moon. He then attacked Wolverine whilst he was drunk from drowning his sorrows after losing most of his friends. During their fight he stabbed Wolverine in the throat with a knife and in the chest with Wolverine's own claws and threw him into an electrical generator. Wolverine's claws pierced the generator and Wolverine was electrocuted until he basically melted down to just his skeleton.

In some stories that wouldn't be enough to kill him. In some it is. This is obviously the latter.

Comment: Good answer, especially the last sentence!

Comment: Also, welcome to the site!

Comment: Also, in some instances it would have been impossible to get Wolverine drunk!

Comment: This isn't true - he was thrown in to *maximum voltage*, which is the maximum. Remember that this was a 90s comic, so that the maximum was even more maximum than normal - when read today, it should be read as *MAXXXimum Voltage*. That would kill all the wolverine's in all the universes.

Answer (score 15):

He throws Wolverine into some sort of "Maximum Voltage" panel ...

[image]

... which electrocutes him:

[image]