# What are Dark Claw's weaknesses?

Tags: marvel, dc, comics, dark-claw, amalgam-comics

With the creation of Amalgam Comics came the creation of the most '90s character to ever exist in the form of Dark Claw. He is a combination of Batman and Wolverine, and really, a poor combination at that. He has the healing factor and claws of Wolverine and the detective skills, martial arts, and everything else of Batman.

Now, with that combination of abilities, what are his weaknesses, if any?

For some context, here's a picture of Dark Claw:

[image: cover of "Legends of the Dark Claw"]

Comment: Well for starters, he looks like he's completely insane.

Comment: More or less insane than a guy who dresses as a bat and puts "Bat-" before everyday objects to turn them into crime fighting implements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** the usual "<s>Bruce</s> Logan Wayne coping with his parents' murder" is the only weakness which is somewhat confirmed, but enough electricity could also be a runner-up.

---

There is (unfortunately) very little Dark Claw material, both in comics and interviews, and said material doesn't display much of Dark Claw getting his butt handed to him. Out of [all his appearances, listed by ComicVine](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/dark-claw/4005-47080/issues-cover/), *Dark Claw Adventures* (1997) offers the most hints at the guy's weaknesses.

- **half-admitted by Dark Claw:** after his fight with a revengeful Lady Talia (the amalgaming of Talia al Ghul and Lady Deathstrike), Dark Claw admitted that for a long time, the possibility of having to face the guy who shot his parents made his mind "fire and pain". He eventually sorted it out in figuring such a situation could only go two ways; given the usual Batman lore, we can assume Dark Claw would at least be frozen by shock/trauma, making that enough of a "weakness" for the other guy to take the upper hand.

  [image: Dark Claw talks about facing his parents' murderer]

- **strongly hinted at by Lady Talia:** pursuant to the above, Talia was able to track him down to his cave with a bio-tracker his mutant senses didn't pick up, but more interestingly, she was able to *break in* because she knew of Dark Claw's backstory. All your passwords relying on the same pattern is poor security, thus qualifying as a weakness. <s>Ask any sysadmin around.</s> The "private obsessions" she refers to is also likey to induce trauma reactions if brought properly. *(as it happens more or less frequently with Batman)*

  [image: How Lady Talia was able to break into the cave]

- **Does not deal well with electricity:** in the first pages of *Dark Claw Adventures*, Dark Claw is zapped by a cyborg, which motivates him to go for this guy first. Sure, Dark Claw has his healing factor, but the other cyborg in the room has a gun, yet he still comes after the "electricity" one in terms of priority. This suggests that electricity impairs Dark Claw enough to be considered a weakness. This makes sense, with the adamantium skeleton; after all, in *Punisher kills the Marvel Universe* (1995), Punisher managed to kill Wolverine by throwing him in a maximum voltage panel, melting him to death (see [How did Punisher kill Wolverine?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/25248/98028)).

  [image: Dark Claw is fried by pure electricity]

- **Apollo's eye blasts:** it's not really enough to draw actual conclusions, but in *JLX* (1996), Dark Claw was blasted by Apollo (the amalgaming of the Ray and Cyclops), causing him some pain.

  [image: Dark Claw blasted by Ray]

---

As per other media than the comics stories:

- There isn't much info of relevance in the "interviews" written in the last pages of Amalgam comics issues;
- I found only [one actual interview from the artist](http://sktchd.com/longform/dc-vs-marvel-oral-history/) (for Sktchd), which, while it gives interesting details about how the Amalgam was set up, and particulary on the secrecy of Dark Claw's creation, does not dwell on the guy's weaknesses;
- there *might* be some info in [issue #69 of *Wizard: the magazine of comics*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16IHq.jpg) ("Your guide to the Marvel/DC crossover!"), but I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

Since Dark Claw is a direct merging of Batman and Wolverine's origin and abilities, one can surmise that Dark Claw has weaknesses from both too.

So, Dark Claw is at the mercy of magnetism, mental attacks, disintegration, Forge's mutant neutralizer and anything to do with the trauma of witnessing your parents murdered in front of you at the age of 5.

Dark Claw also inherited Batman's conscience which made him a failure in the eyes of the Weapon X program.